# The "shinyFeedback" not works for "dateRangeInput" component

Tags: r, shiny

I try to test "shinyFeedback" package for processing dates and can't run this test code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
  uiOutput("uo_numeric"),
  uiOutput("uo_date_range")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Numeric
  output$uo_numeric <-  renderUI({
    numericInput("n", "Label", value = 10)
  }) 
  
  # Date range
  output$uo_date_range <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput(
      "si_date_range", "Date range",
      start = as.Date(lubridate::now()),
      end = as.Date(lubridate::now()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(
    input$si_date_range, {
      print(!is.na(input$si_date_range))
      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning(
        "si_date_range", !is.na(input$si_date_range),
        "Please select a valid dates")
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    input$n, shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning(
      "n", input$n %% 2 != 0, "Please select an even number")  
  )
  
} # server

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any ideas on how to make "dateRangeInput" workable?

Thanks

Comment: the `input$si_date_range` should be a vector of 2 elements (first and second dates). You could use `is.na` to see if a date entered is blank, and also check to make sure your first date precedes your second date, something like: `shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("si_date_range", as.Date(input$si_date_range[1]) > as.Date(input$si_date_range[2]) | any(is.na(input$si_date_range)), "Please select valid dates")` ... would that have the validation you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, @Ben But it not shows me warnings. If you replace "!is.na(input$si_date_range)" on TRUE or FALSE - nothing happens

Comment: @Ben Yes, please :)

Comment: I used shiny 1.5.0 and shinyFeedback 0.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version.

`input$si_date_range` should be a vector of 2 elements (first and second dates).

You could use `is.na` to see if either date entered is blank. The `feedbackWarning` can also check to make sure your first date precedes your second date.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Numeric
  output$uo_numeric <-  renderUI({
    numericInput("n", "Label", value = 10)
  }) 
  
  # Date range
  output$uo_date_range <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput(
      "si_date_range", "Date range",
      start = as.Date(lubridate::now()),
      end = as.Date(lubridate::now()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(
    input$si_date_range, {
      print(input$si_date_range)
      shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning(
        "si_date_range", 
        as.Date(input$si_date_range[1]) > as.Date(input$si_date_range[2]) | 
                any(is.na(input$si_date_range)),
        "Please select valid dates")
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    input$n, shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning(
      "n", input$n %% 2 != 0, "Please select an even number")  
  )
  
} # server
```

Comment: It still not works. I tried to use as TRUE as FALSE here "shinyFeedback::feedbackWarning("si_date_range", TRUE, "Please select valid dates")" - seems problems with calling "feedbackWarning"

Comment: It also works for "dateInput" element but not for "dateRangeInput"

Comment: Yes, sure. I did it and rechecked it, and restarted R session. Not works for inputDateRange

Comment: It works on another machine with shiny 1.4.0 and not works on shiny 1.5.0. The shinyFeedback is up-to-date. Maybe 1.5.0 shiny not support it for dateRange

Comment: yes very strange i tested it on aws web rstudio with 1.4.0 shiny - it seems works - but not works for local Mac with 1.5.0 shiny

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to the question.
https://github.com/merlinoa/shinyFeedback/issues/51#issuecomment-715997550

The package re-installing by using "remotes::install_github("merlinoa/shinyFeedback")" fixed problem on my side.